# TeamCity artifacts packaging

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

TeamCity has very useful feature to get all the artifacts after build - Download all (.zip)

I wonder if there is a way to somehow calculate check sum for that aggregated zip (say, MD5)? Of course i can setup a new build configuration that will download artifacts, calculate the sum and publish it but i'm looking for simple solution.

Comment: so you calculate the md5sum somehow (eg using md5sum.exe) then what do you want to do with it? ie where are you wanting to publish it ?

Comment: Maybe as a comment to svn tag? Maybe as a filename of the aggregated zip, don't know. I thought TeamCity offers something like postbuild action or something. Anyway, i can add a last step to the build that will archive all the outputs i need, calculate check sum into a text file and add that archive and file to the artifacts. Just want to know if there is simpler way.

Comment: as an aside, you can add your artifacts to a zip file without needing to add a build step. On your configuration page in artifacts path you can specify the target zip, eg
YourProj\bin\Debug\* => artifacts.zip!/myapp. see here for more http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up with a custom step to zip all artifacts, then calculate the check sum and let TeamCity to autozip my archive and the sum file.